# Is there anyway to get rid of the shutdown/sleep option in the lock screen in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, power

The reason why is quite complicated and cant be explained ATM. I'm pretty sure there's an option for it in the settings but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit the start button and type in `secpol` and run the "Local Security Policy" progam.

From in that program navigate to "Security Settings -> Local Polices -> Security Options" on the right side go to "Shutdown: Allow system to be shut down without having to log in" and double click it.

[image]

In the new window set the setting to "Disabled` and click OK. Once you click OK the option to shutdown/sleep/restart the computer disappears from the lock screen.